# App en IOS a través de TestFlight no coge internet

Tags: ios, ionic3, proxy, networking

He creado una App en ionic tanto para ios como para Android.
Para poder probarla, he tenido que crear un proxy para ejecutar las llamadas GET y POST desde el navegador (sino no se pueden hacer).

En Android no hay problema, quito el proxy a la hora de generar el apk y pasarlo a mi dispositivo y todas las llamadas GET y POST funcionan.

A la hora de generar el instalador para IOS, lo paso a XCode sin quitar el proxy y no funciona(quiero pensar que es por el proxy que no puedo hacer las llamadas) pero quito el proxy y tampoco funciona!

No se si es por el tema proxy o por instalarla a través de TestFlight.

¿Alguien sabe algo del tema? He encontrado esta misma pregunta en SO pero sin respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32094672/ios-testflight-app-cant-connect-to-the-internet

Comment: Posiblemente no funcione porque estas usando http y no https, por defecto las apps en iOS no soportan conecciones inseguras. Para probar podes modificar el info.plist para que las permita, aun asi lo mejor seria que consigas un certificado https

Comment: mmm... no creo que sea por eso, ios si que soporta las conexiones http. La solución ha sido utilizar el plugin http-advanced y no el que usaba anteriormente, con ese cambio a funcionar

Answer (score 0):

puede ser un error de "permisos" en iOS y añadir lo siguiente:

```
  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
  <key>*</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
 </dict>
```